# Is there a web-service that would convert httptext response into xmlstring response?

Tags: xml, web-services

I'm using a web-service that's returning response as follows:

```
result_id=123&result_message="Failed"&...
```

The interface I'm using it in doesn't have any fancy parsing methods or any coding options in general. It could parse xml though.

How do I turn the above response into

```
<result_id>123</result_id><result_message>Failed</result_message>
```

Is there some free-to-use web-service that is already taking care of this or any other way-out you can think of? The web-service I'm using doesn't have any xml response option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the response with &. i.e., if the response is in varialbe res

```
String[] resArr = res.split("&");
```

create a method which will accpet two arguments 1) tag. 2) value

```
public String getXmlTag(String tag,String val) {
String result = "<tag>val<tag/>";
result.replaceAll("tag",tag);
result.replaceAll("val",val);
return result;
}
```

You can substring each entry in resArr and get the tag and val and pass it to this method. And concatinate to get the xml.

P S : the above getXmlTag will not work if the tag name is val :P

Comment: If I could split and all, I wouldn't need to convert it to xml. I don't have any string functions exception concatenate etc and I can't even code my own due to the limitation of the interface.

Comment: Can you use substring method? I didn't get you why you can't use split and all.

Comment: because I'm not using PHP or any other programming language. I am using their interface - which allows some very basic methods like - calling web-service and parsing xml result. I can use substring though - it's one of their basic methods.

Comment: I think you can do the same with substring aswell. You can't take substring till = and from = to &.